# Sobre o segundo video do Nightmare, meu personagem nao fica animaçao em loop

Tags: loop

Minha duvida é a respeito de animação de personagem.
O tutorial que eu segui é o do "Jogando com o Nils"
O video é "Unity3D - Como criar personagem, animacao e movimento - Nightmare - Unity Training Day 2014 #02"

A ferramenta que estou utilizando é o Unity 4.6.9

No video se trata de um joguinho que ele está explicando como foi feito.

Para seguir seu tutorial, baixei um personagem de internet, possui as animações todas no lugar porem, após seguir todos os passos, as animações do personagem não ficam em um loop, elas executam uma vez e para...

[image: .]

Esta é a tela do animator, onde o movimento da barrinha azul está normal, porém não repete a animação.

Então meu problema é que a animação não se repete, nem a "Run" nem a "Stand", tudo foi feito como o video e eu nao obtive o mesmo resultado, podem me ajudar?

Comment: Expliquei melhor meu problema..
desculpe, minha primeira vez aqui

Comment: Melhorou bastante, mas só olhando o que vc escreveu acho que ainda fica dificil vermos qual é a parte que controlaria o loop do personagem. Talvez se vc clicasse nos nós responsaveis por essas partes e acrescentasse screenshots dos parâmetros, ajudasse. De qq forma, vamos ver se alguém que tem prática disso deixa algum comentário perguntando mais detalhes. Talvez se vc deixar o link da sua pergunta (tem um link "compartilhar" logo abaixo da pergunta, pra pegar o link) no canal do Nils ele mesmo venha ajudar.

Comment: De qq forma, o passo mais importante vc deu, que é ter a boa vontade de melhorar. Com o tempo vc vai acostumando com a comunidade e fazendo um melhor proveito do site, principalmente nas dúvidas de programação com código (se bem que eu entendo que blueprints são programação também, mesmo que visual, por isso recomendei acrescentar na pergunta também).

Comment: Okay, vou enviar a pergunta pra ele, afinal ele me mandou esse link para tirar minha duvida mas eu pensei que fosse algo que ele estivesse gerenciando kk, obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: @KleitonDiones a animação não fica em loop no jogo também, ou só no animator?
Você poderia postar uma captura de tela do inspector da animação que está usando, por favor?

Comment: @KleitonDiones e do personagem que esse animator faz parte também.